# SharePoint 2010 Bulletin Board - User can only edit their post

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to create a bulletin board in SharePoint 2010 and ideally we'd like people to make posts but they should only be able to edit their posts and not others.

Is this possible at all?

Also if anyone knows of any off the shelf solutions (not necessarily with the above mentioned edit abilities) that I could trial please let me know.

Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, in advanced list properties you can set an option to edit only your own posts however where I was going wrong is the UI still shows the edit option but you get an "access denied" message when you try and save....Great